# How to install libc6-i386 libc6-dev-i386 on Ubuntu 18.04 32-bit Virtual Machine?

Tags: 18.04, apt

I set two virtual machines. One is the mail-server and the other one is the client.

On the mail-server I've tried using

```
apt install libc6-i386 libc6-dev-i386
```

and

```
apt-get install libc6-i386 libc6-dev-i386
```

Both of them give error messages:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libc6-i386 is not available, but is referred to by another
package.

This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
 is only available from another source

However the following packages replace it:

  libc6
 
E: Package 'libc6-i386' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libc6-dev-i386
```

What shall I do?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt install gcc-multilib`? This package containging support for 32bit libc.

Comment: No, I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your package lists first by

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And then install the packages by

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 libc6-dev-i386
```